# Python - Opening Multible Tabs in Internet Explorer

Tags: python, internet-explorer, browser

I'm using this code to open Google in IE...

```
ie = webbrowser.get('C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.exe')

ie.open('http://google.com")
```

I need to open multiple tabs though, so how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested with IE, but this is the way it's *supposed* to work:

```
ie.open_new_tab(url1)
ie.open_new_tab(url2)
ie.open_new_tab(url3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ie.open_new_tab('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open_new_tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you! You just need to wait the main windows load to open a new tab.

`import win32com.client, time
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://www.yahoo.com')
time.sleep(2) #wait 2 sec. 
webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://www.google.com.br')`